# How to Call a Table from a Variable in Lua?

Tags: lua, computercraft

I'm creating a program for a turtle in ComputerCraft. The program is going to make the turtle control a warehouse of storage for my items in the game. It will check what item I put in, then it will figure out the chest's location, go there, and dump it in. I am storing the locations of each chest in a table. For example:

```
cobblestone = {2,0,1}
```

That tells the turtle that the cobblestone chest is stored at position x=2 y=0 and z=1. To get the turtle to tell what it needs to store, it does:

```
itemDetails = turtle.getItemDetail()
name = string.gsub(itemDetails.name, "minecraft:", "")
```

This gets the turtle to get the details of the item. It then sets a variable to be the name of the item minus the minecraft: at the beginning of it (I can't have a variable called "minecraft:cobblestone"). I don't know how to use this variable to call the table and find its position for the turtle to go to it. If anybody can help, I would appreciate any of the help. Thanks in advance!
Also, just a heads up, the code is still set up for debugging and testing purposes. The setup is a turtle, with an input chest in front of it, a fuel chest to the right, and the warehouse behind it.

I've tried doing:

```
cobblestone = {2,0,1}
--Putting a piece of cobblestone in--
itemDetails = turtle.getItemDetail()
--Returning name of "minecraft:cobblestone"--
name = string.gsub(itemDetails.name, "minecraft:", "")
print name[1]
```

So far this hasn't worked.

```
pos = {0,0,0}
looking = 0
cobblestone = {2,0,1}
function fuel()
    if turtle.getFuelLevel() < 20 then
        turtle.select(16)
        turtle.refuel(1)
    end
end
function left()
    turtle.turnLeft()
    looking = looking - 1
    if looking < 0 then
        looking = 3
    end
        print(looking)
end
function right()
    turtle.turnRight()
    looking = looking + 1
    if looking > 3 then
        looking = 0
    end
        print(looking)
end
function forward()
    fuel()
        if turtle.forward() then
            if looking == 0 then
                pos[1] = pos[1] - 1
            elseif looking == 1 then
                pos[3] = pos[3] - 1 
            elseif looking == 2 then
                pos[1] = pos[1] + 1
            elseif looking == 3 then
                pos[3] = pos[3] + 1
            else
                print("wot")
            end
        end

end
function up()
    fuel()
    turtle.up()
    pos[2] = pos[2] + 1
end
function down()
    fuel()
    turtle.down()
    pos[2] = pos[2] - 1
end
function goHome()
    while pos[3] > 0 do
        while  looking > 1 do
            left()
        end
        forward()
    end
    while  pos[2] > 0 do
        down()
    end
    while  pos[1] > 0 do
        while  looking > 0 do
            left()
        end
        forward()
    end
end

while true do
    turtle.select(1)
    while not turtle.suck() do
        sleep(1)
    end
    itemDetails = turtle.getItemDetail()
    name = string.gsub(itemDetails.name, "minecraft:", "")
    print(name)
        while looking < 2 or looking > 2 do
            left()
        end
        for i = pos[1],name[1]-1 do
            forward()
        end
        while looking > 3 or looking < 3 do
            right()
        end
        for i = pos[3],name[3]-1 do
            forward()
        end
        for i = pos[2],name[2]-1 do
            up()
        end
        while looking < 2 or looking > 2 do
            left()
        end
        turtle.select(1)
        turtle.drop()
        goHome()
end
```

I want to be able to do:

```
cobblestone = {2,0,1}
--Putting a piece of cobblestone in--
itemDetails = turtle.getItemDetail()
--Returning name of "minecraft:cobblestone"--
name = string.gsub(itemDetails.name, "minecraft:", "")
print name[1]
```

and have the turtle print the same thing as
    cobblestone[1]
which would be 2. However, it returns with nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your `cobblestone` is global, what is bad for this example. At first, store all elements like this:

```
local myelems = {
   cobblestone = {2,0,1};
   grass = {3,1,2};
}
```

and so on. Use `local` variables when you can, it's good practice in programming at all.

So let's look at your code:

```
-- Returning name of "minecraft:cobblestone"
local name = string.gsub(itemDetails.name, "minecraft:", "")
print(name[1])
```

What it does? (I've changed it a bit)

At first,`string.gsub` look like an overkill here, use `string.match` instead:

```
local name = itemDetails.name:match("^minecraft:(.+)$")
```

Here `itemDetails.name:match` is same as calling `string.match` with `itemDetails.name` as first argument. It can be used for all `string` functions.

So here `name` is **string** variable. Indexing strings in different languages may have different results. In lua in actually provide access to all `string` functions to make calls to them easier (as above). There is no such function as `string[1]`, so you get `nil`. However, now we have table `myelems` in which keys are strings and values are your tables.

Full code:

```
-- Table for all elements
local myelems = {
   cobblestone = {2,0,1};
   grass = {3,1,2};
}
-- Putting a piece of cobblestone in
local itemDetails = turtle.getItemDetail()
--Returning name of "minecraft:cobblestone"
local name = itemDetails.name:match("^minecraft:(.+)$")
-- Get our table
local elem = myelems[name]
if elem then
  print(elem[1], elem[2], elem[3])
end
```